# How do you input a list of characters from the user using arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to build a basic program which will take names from the user and will display the number of names back which contains more than 5 alphabets.

```
from array import*

list=array('u',[])

n=int(input("Enter the number of names first"))

for i in range(0,n):

    y=input("Enter the names one by one")
    list.append(y)
```

But when running this code I am getting an error

> "TypeError: array item must be unicode character"

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How does this code perform differently than expected?

Comment: check for the `len` of `y`, `if  > 5` store in a `list` and then print that list.

Comment: The `u` type code corresponds to Python’s obsolete unicode character.

Comment: Using `keywords` as a `name` for your list is not considered a good practice either, Use `lst` or `namesList` anything that differentiates it from the keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, keep it simple for your understanding:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of names first"))

nameLst = []           # an empty list to store the desired names
for i in range(0,n):
    y = input("Enter the names one by one")     
    if len(y) > 5:               # if the len of name is > 5
        nameLst.append(y)        # append it to the list

for i in range(len(nameLst)):    # iterate over the len of the list
    print(nameLst[i])            # print all the names in the list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input('enter times : '))
name =list(map(str, input("enter name spe by space : ").strip().split()))
if len(name)==n:
    name2 =[i for i in name if len(i)>=5]
    print("name are ->", *name2)

"""
output 

enter times : 3

enter name spe by space : john edward philips
name are -> edward philips

"""
```

Comment: I Used a list instead of an array , and it worked fine still i am a little confused why the array was not working,


i used a function to print the number of names which contain more than 5 alphabets.